# Hiding Reference Errors using Font colour in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi there i have this code which changes cells with reference errors to white fonts. However i could only do so for a single sheet. range. How do i change the for each loop to loop for all the worksheets in the workbook? I used this code below but it does not seem to work!

```
Sub Delete_ref_basedontextcondition()


    Dim R As Range


    'Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)
    Dim rng As Range



   If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    R.Delete
   End If


For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets

  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)


For Each cell In wks
 If cell.Text = "#REF!" Then
  cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
 End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: it runs but does not removes the  reference errors! @pnuts

Comment: Does it change the `Cell.Font.Color`? As your code states change `Cell.Font.Color` not `.ClearContents` thus it doesn't remove the reference errors.

Comment: The colours do change when i run it on a single sheet. For example if i used for each cell in "Sheet name" it changes all reference error cells to white fonts. but i cant do so for all sheets using this code. so i need help! @DragonSamu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I disagree with your method of hiding `#REF!` errors rather than dealing with them so that they are *not* `#REF!` errors (or deleting the formulas that are creating them, here is some standard 'loop-through-the-worksheets' code that you should be able to adapt for your purposes.

```
Sub bad_ref()
    Dim w As Long, ref As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    For w = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(w)
            For Each ref In .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                If ref.Text = "#REF!" Then
                    ref.Font.ColorIndex = 2
                    'ref.clear   '<~~this clears formatting, formulas. etc from the rogue cell.
                End If
            Next ref
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

It should run through quickly enough. Rather than examine every cell on each worksheet, I've narrowed down the cells to be critiqued with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx), looking only through the formulas that produce errors. Something like a `#N/A` error will be left alone.

I've left an option to actually do something with the errors as a commented line.

Comment: I have a code to remove all ref errors in the next sub of my programme:) I have just hide it so that it wont look "unattractive" when users want to access the excel file. Thus i hide it first then clear content of all cells with underlying ref errors @Jeeped

Comment: @Niva use     `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` at the begin of your code and set it to `True` at the end of your code. This stops any flickering and updating on your screen thus not being "unattractive" for the user.